# GridView paging control issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I m using Grid view web control of asp.net ,i m using paging control in that, i handled paging event in that but it does not show data if i click on 2,3,4... so on link it is not displaying one result set..it does not give any exception but just displays nothing apart first page.here is the code :

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected string PostBackOption = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.check.Text = " ";
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PostBackOption = "$(\"#dialog\").dialog(\"open\");";
    }
}

List<Allemployees> result1 = new List<Allemployees>();
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // Show all the employees currently in the table
    GridView1.DataSource = null;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    using (var db = new AdventureWorks2012_DataEntities())
    {

        List<Allemployees> result = new List<Allemployees>();
        var query = from b in db.Employees
                    join p in db.People on b.BusinessEntityID equals p.BusinessEntityID
                    orderby p.BusinessEntityID
                    select new
                    {
                        b.BusinessEntityID,
                        p.FirstName,
                        p.LastName
                    };

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Allemployees t1 = new Allemployees();
            t1.BusinessEntityId = item.BusinessEntityID;
            t1.FirstName = item.FirstName;
            t1.LastName = item.LastName;
            result1.Add(t1);
        }
     GridView1.DataSource = result1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    } 
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = result1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your GridView1_PageIndexChanging into this:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gridview = (GridView)sender;

    gridview.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    Button1_Click(null, null);

    gridview.DataBind();
}
```

Make sure to make GridView1 AllowPaging to true.

Let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks it worked but i have another problem i have 25  Button?_Click(null, null); events ..now resolve it?

Comment: Please re-phrase your question, sorry I didn't get it. :(

Comment: i mean i have 25 more button handler how i can encounter it

Comment: sorry I can't imagine what you want to do, in your question the problem you have is only for the pagination of your gridview.

Answer (score 0):

reason is when you click the link page postback and `result1` will not have any value. if you want to keep the data while postback you have to use viewstate, session etc..

in `Button1_Click` do as below

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // your code 
    GridView1.DataBind(); // add below line after this line
    Session["Data"] = result1; 
}
```

in `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` method

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    var result = (List<Allemployees>)Session["Data"];
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = result;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: @DanishAhmad i have update my answer with how to use `Session` try that

Answer (score 0):

remove line
GridView1.DataSource=result1 in page changing function.